# Using Symlinks in iOS Localizations

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization

Folks,

I'll do some experimenting, but I think it's a good idea to ask for the "official word."

I have an app that is localized for Farsi ('fa'). However, there are actually 3 "brands" of Farsi: Farsi (fa), Farsi-Iran (fa-IR) and Farsi-Afghanistan (fa-AF). Now, thanks to [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998250/iphone-ios-how-do-i-tell-what-localization-the-phone-is-using-at-runtime), I can set the proper calendar. However, another aspect of my localization is that I have a series of 24-bit PNG images that are used for localizations.

These are not small. I'd like to re-use the fa images for the other two (less common) ones.

Can I symlink to them? Will the symlinks carry into the device?

.
.
Anyone?
.
.
Bueller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test if this really works, but I would expect that if you include the files only in 'fa' and leave them out of 'fa-IR' and 'fa-AF' that the runtime should be smart enough to use the image from 'fa' if it can't find one when running in 'fa-IR' or in 'fa-AF', instead of defaulting to say 'en'.