# NSBundle preferredLocalizations doesn't return the most specific localization available

Tags: ios, localization

I have both "en" and "en-AU" (Australian English) localizations for a particular file.

While the current locale is "en_AU", `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations]` produces the set of localizations I expect:

```
( "en-AU", "en" )
```

However, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]` (the one that actually matters) produces only:

```
( "en" )
```

Why is the most specific supported localization omitted entirely from the preferred list and a more generic localization returned instead?

Is there a way can I get `NSBundle` to prioritize the most precise available localization above less specific options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because your phone is set to use English and not Australian English. I looked through the list of supported languages on my phone and I couldn't find Australian English. Just English and British English, so that's probably why.

**EDIT:**

I think you should read this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF

As I understand you, this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
```

prints `en_AU` and that's not the same thing as `en-AU`. If you've read the linked documentation you already know the difference. For instance `en-GB_AU` means British English spoken in Australia, which would be appropriate for a British person in Australia.

Anyway, did you try changing `en-AU` to `en_AU` in your bundle?

Comment: English is the language, Australia is the region. If you set your language to English and your region format to Australia, you'll get the locale "en_AU" (which you can verify by asking NSLocale for the currentLocale).

Comment: Sure, but there's a distinction between locale and localization. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7204733/310121
I'm don't claim to be an expert, but I think the locale decides currency, clock format etc, while localization decides what language is used. At least that seemed to be the case when I had `en_US` as locale and `sv` as localization, because everything was in Swedish.

Comment: As I understand it a localization is essentially a set of content for a particular locale. It makes sense that they wouldn't match up if you don't have a localization for a given locale. But in this case I have a localization that is exactly the same as the current locale, yet for some reason it's not considered a/the preferred localization.

Comment: @BWW Did you try changing `en-AU` to `en_AU` in your bundle?

Comment: Thanks! I was specifying the locale via the popup list in Xcode, which then automatically organizes files into the <locale/language>.lproj directories; it was using the language rather than the locale. (I didn't appreciate the distinction between en_AU and en-AU before reading the documentation you linked.)